# Regex splitting on period unnecessarily

Tags: c#, regex

I am splitting a string using this regex expression.

```
 inputSplit =  Regex.Split(temp, @"([/+-/*x/÷///²/√])")
```

This expression should split on +-*x÷/²√.This works perfectly except when I put in a decimal. 
If i do 1 + .002 it splits into 1, +, ., 002. Which i cant find out why its splitting the decimal from the .002. I assume its maybe one of my special characters? Thanks

Comment: No matter what the fix, you shouldn't use special character literal's in regular expressions, ever. Use the code point or hex code if ascii. Regular expressions should always be depicted as ascii text.

Comment: Ok thanks with just the little i have been messing with it i can see how that would help avoid a lot of unnecessary problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to revise your expresion probably missing `\` next to `-`

```
([+\-*x÷²√])
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rU2qB0)

This I think is returning your expected results:

```
var results = Regex.Split("1+.002", @"([+\-*x÷²√])", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: Too fast, the correct expression is : ([+\-*x÷/²√])

Comment: In PCRE, placing a hyphen at the end of a character class takes away its special semantics and treats it like a literal.  ...just an alternative to backslash escaping, though I don't know if that approach works with C#

Answer (score 2):

Your `+-/` is matching anything between `+` to `/`.

```
@"([+\-/*x÷²√])"
```